# C# Winforms Help Text Change font

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little help pop-up that displays some text when the user presses a "?" label next to a drop-down to explain the different selections.

I did it using the Help.ShowPopup command since that seemed the easiest.

I was hoping there was a way to add different font properties to parts of the text or at least to the whole thing without having to go the direction of a CHM/HTML help-file.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
private void helpLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // for some reason, it ignores the 'parent' parameter 
    // and lays it out on the screen's coordinates
    Point helpLocation = helpLbl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty); 
    helpLocation.Y += helpLbl.Height; // have it display underneath the control

    Help.ShowPopup(this,  // hosting form
@"<b>Fixed:</b>
Removes a fixed amount from the sale
<b>Percent Value:</b>
Removes a set percentage of the selected package from the sale
...", helpLocation);
```

I was hoping since there's the option to use an HTML document to display the help, I could use HTML tags to format what was being displayed, but it doesn't appear so. Any ideas?

Is there a way to do something like displaying a RichTextBox in the help pop-up?

Another possibility is generating a HTML document on-the-fly, but it asks for a "url" if I'm not supplying the text directly and I think that might be  a little over-kill for the small amount I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Why not write your own help box? Poping up a Control or a form is not hard and you can design it to your needs, including a RTB..

Comment: Well I was hoping to use the built-in functionality for help so it would look the same as what people expect across OS versions and user settings and all that. It was a small feature that QA asked for.
ps: sorry for the wall-of-text and thanks for spacing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. One is to use a [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This natively accepts HTML and displays it. The problem with it is its kind of bloated just to use as a simple label.

Your second option is to simply create a RichTextLabel, simply like this:

```
public class RichTextLabel : RichTextBox
{
    public RichTextLabel()
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

Add this to your form and set the [Rtf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx) property to your RTF code. You will have to convert your HTML to RTF, which is easy if you got a program such as Microsoft Word, for example.